# print 1 to 10 using increment operator

Tags: java, operators, increment

I need some help with my code. It prints `a`, not 1 to 10, as desired. What am I missing here?

```
public class numeros
{
     public static void main(String args[])    
     {
         int a;
         for (a=1; a<=10; a++)
         {
             System.out.println( "a");
         }     
     }
}
```

It prints:

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: It's doing just what you tell it to do -- printing the "a" string. Instead you want it to print the `a` variable -- `System.out.println("" + a);` or `System.out.println(String.valueOf(a));`

Comment: Word to the wise, OP: watch your code indentation. Your original edit was hard to follow, both for me and likely for you. Your grader probably won't be too happy with it either. :)

Answer (score 4):

`"a"` is a string, not the variable `a`. Change `"a"` into `"Bugs Bunny"` and hopefully it will make it clear what's happening :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the String "a", not the value of the variable `a`.

The simplest thing to do is to do

`System.out.println(a);`

If you look in the Javadocs, you'll see that `println` has many signatures, so it can take many different argument types.

Comment: OMG im such a noob :( sorry im just in first semester

Answer (score 1):

```
class numeros{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  int a;
  for(a = 1; a < 10; a++)
  {
     System.out.println(""+a);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the variable, not the string "a".

```
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass a string  with the value "a" instead of the variable a to System.out.printLn,  try System.out.println(a) instead